# LESS - Is there a way to group styles applied to a certain selector together and then apply it in another file?

Tags: css, less

Let's say I have a LESS file like this:

```
.wrapper-1 {
    .textbox { // styles }

    .textbox::placeholder { // styles }

    .checkbox { // styles }

    .button { // styles } 

    .some + other > complicated.selector::here { // styles }
}
```

Now, say I want to apply the styles within `.wrapper-1` to another file for `.wrapper-2` without having repeat all the styles again.

I want to essentially achieve this without having to repeat all the styles again.

```
.wrapper-2 {
    .textbox { // styles }

    .textbox::placeholder { // styles }

    .checkbox { // styles }

    .button { // styles } 

    .some + other > complicated.selector::here { // styles }
}
```

I started by creating a `common` file like and extracting selectors into their own variables like so:

```
@textbox: ~'.textbox';
@textbox-placeholder: ~'.textbox::placeholder';
@checkbox: ~'.checkbox';
@button: ~'.button';
@someOtherComplicatedSelector: ~'.some + other > complicated.selector::here';

@{textbox} { // styles }
@{textbox-placeholder} { // styles }
@{checkbox} { // styles }
@{button} { // styles }
@{someOtherComplicatedSelector} { // styles }
```

But how do I then apply those "variables" into the proper place I want them to be? I essentially want something like this (obviously, the syntax isn't right):

```
.wrapper-1 {
    @{textbox}
    @{textbox-placeholder}
    @{checkbox}
    @{button}
    @{someOtherComplicatedSelector}
}
```

and

```
.wrapper-2 {
    @{textbox}
    @{textbox-placeholder}
    @{checkbox}
    @{button}
    @{someOtherComplicatedSelector}
}
```

In essence, is there a way to bundle/group styles and selectors together to be applied within other selectors?

Comment: In SCSS I tend to use extends or mixins. Not sure if they are the same in LESS, but you could give it a shot. [Extends](https://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extend-syntax) / [Mixin](https://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature)

Comment: Yes! Extends are great in this situation `.wrapper-2 {&:extend(.wrapper-1);}`